# Are LED's always necessary/desirable?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I don't need or find it aesthetically pleasing to have little green micro-energy leeches illuminating every outlet and switch in my home. are there any GFCI's/outlets/switches that are LED FREE for sale anymore?

Comment: While aesthetics and GFCI don't usually go hand in hand in my world, have you considered a dab of liquid paper on the offending unit?

Answer (score 7):

First note -- a GaN green LED can provide acceptable brightness at sub-milliamp currents, so the amount of energy a status LED on a GFCI draws can easily be reduced to something truly insignificant.

Second -- GFCIs themselves draw a small amount of current for the operating electronics.  Older models draw a dozen mA or so, while newer ones need less than one milliamp -- so even without the LED, you're still going to have a very small quiescent current draw.

Third -- modern GFCIs are required by recent UL943 revisions to have some sort of self-test/end-of-life indication in them.

However, if you really want to banish the little green lights -- getting regular switches and outlets without them is not an issue, and your GFCI protection can migrate into the breaker panel in most cases.

Comment: Thanks for all the Green friendly advice and information from everyone, I am mostly concerned with all the little lightning bugs annoying my eyes - I'll think I'll go with Aloysius "the window destroyer" and break out the White-Out.

Answer (score 5):

An indicator LED of that size takes about 30mW.  Which means 0.03 watts or 1/33 of a watt).  For most Americans, 1 watt of power run continuously costs $1 to $2 a year.  So that indicator is costing you between 3 and 6 cents a year.

While that's bad, it's the **least of your problems**.

Your house is full of vampire loads which are much, Much, MUCH, larger.  I'm guessing you know at least a little about this topic.  Do you own a $20 Kill-a-Watt and measure some of your loads?

It's easy to get confused by the units, so say an efficient wall-wart power supply of 1 watt, $1-2/year is 33 lights. The ubiquitous cable TV box, 35 watts, that's $35-70 or over a thousand indicator lights.  The somewhat more efficient Uverse boxes are about half that.  Cordless phones, a couple of watts.  ($2-5)

Old school wired telephone: 0 watts.  (The needed power is fed down the phone lines from the switching center, which has huge banks of batteries to keep the phone network up 24x7.)

The upshot is that your "energy leech" concern is inapplicable, but I'm glad you care about the issue. As for the stupid light, a magic marker or a bit of tape.

In any case, lights on GFCIs are the exception rather than the rule, you'll have no trouble finding unlit ones.  But I would buy a Kill-a-Watt instead.

Comment: And that GFCI *itself* is probably costing just as much to run if not more.

Comment: True that.  I would slap a GFCI into a junction box and stick a cord on it and plug it into a Kill-a-Watt, but I'd worry the energy consumption of the GFCI would be below the Kill-a-Watt's capacity to measure. Might have to measure it old school.